# jquery xml exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to use javascript / jquery to determine if an xml file exists.
I don't need to process it; I just need to know whether it's available or not,but I can't seem to find a simple check.

Here is what I've tried:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var photo = '223';
    var exists = false;

    jQuery.load('/'+photo+'.xml', function (response, status, req) { 
      if (status == "success") { 
        exists = true;
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: exists where? on the server or locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about an xml file on the server, you could do a ajax request and then write a custom error handler to check the error response message. You'll need to know what the exact error message code is for a missing file (usually 404). You can use Firebug Console to check what the exact error message and code is.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "text.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
        alert("great success");
     }, 
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        if(xhr.status == 404)
        {
            alert("xml file not found");
        } else {
            //some other error occured, statusText will give you the error message
            alert("error: " + xhr.statusText);
        }
     } //end error
 }); //close $.ajax(
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it seems like it would make more sense to check `xhr.status === 404`, rather than `xhr.statusText == "Not Found"`, as status will contain a numerical error code rather than arbitrary string which may or may not even be set by the server's error handler depending on the implementer. If you really wanted to be robust you could check `if(xhr.status >== 400) { alert('failed'); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear to me. If I understand, you want to verify whether a file (the XML) is present or not in the HTTP server.

That's correct? If so, you can just do:

```
$.get('url-to-file.xml', function(response, status, req) {
    if (status == 'success') {
        alert('exists');
    }
});
```

EDITED: As pointed by @lzyy on comments, .get() only calls the callback upon success. However, I'd stick to the .load() using $(document) as selector. See:

```
$(document).load('url-to-file.xml', function(response, status, req) {
    if (status == 'success') {
        alert('exists');
    } else if (status == 'error') {
        alert('doesnt exist');
    }
});
```

Comment: currently I'm getting jQuery.load is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I meant $.get(). Fixed the snippet.

Comment: $.get()'s callback function will be executed only if the response has a successful response code

Comment: @lzyy indeed. Thanks for the note! I used .load() at first because it works the way he expected, but then I figured out it can't be used without a selector. However, I'd suggest him to use $(document) as selector.